# How to clear the data from DataStore Preferences in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

I want to know how can I clear the data from Data Store Preferences in Android. In my use-case when the user presses the Logout I want to clear the saved authentication code from the data store preferences.

Upon searching I found there was a way to do it in Shared Preferences using `edit()` and `clear()` method, but I can't find any such methods in Data Store Preferences. Also the blog by Android developers doesn't have any information about it.

Comment: Afaik, there's a `clear` method on `MutablePreferences`. You could try `dataStore.edit { clear() }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear your preferences using this way

```
requireContext().dataStore.edit {
it.remove(key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Shafaat and @DarShan there are two ways to clear data from DataStore Preferences.

1. Clearing all the data in the data store preferences

```
context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
    preferences.clear()
}
```

2. If you want to remove the specific token (value) from DataStore

```
context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
    preferences.remove(YOUR_TOKEN)
}
```